# Proof of a fact involved two cars motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> Two cars A and B start to move in the same direction. A starts to move with acceleration $5 m/s^2$ and B with $4 m/s^2$. After 15 min A runs with uniform velocity. B continuously runs with acceleration $4 m/s^2$.

Is it possible to determine how many times the two cars meet mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

If the two cars start at the same time and place, they can only pass once:

[image]

However, they can pass twice if B is given a head start in either time or distance.

e.g. if they start at the same place but B leaves first:
[image]

or if they start at the same time but B starts off some distance in front of A:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A is initially faster than B. A remains faster than B until a certain time. At that certain time B starts travelling faster than A. B catches up with A and passes it. Intuitively anyway, the cars would "meet" once.